# Regex global search without using the global flag

Tags: regex

I'm using software that only allows a single line regular expression for filtering and it doesn't allow the global modifier to capture all patterns in the string. Currently, my expression is only returning the first instance.

Is there another way to capture all instances of the pattern in the string?

Expression: (captures hi-res jpg urls)

```
\{\"hiRes\"\:\"([A-Za-z0-9%\/_:.-]+)\"\,\"thumb
```

String:

```
'colorImages': { 'initial': [{"hiRes":"http://sub.website.com/images/I/81OJ6qwKxyL._SL1500_.jpg","thumb":"http://sub.website.com/images/I/41NQRigTUdL._SS40_.jpg","large":"http://sub.website.com/images/I/41NQRigTUdL.jpg","main":{"http://sub.website.com/images/I/81OJ6qwKxyL._SY355_.jpg":[272,355],"http://sub.website.com/images/I/81OJ6qwKxyL._SY450_.jpg":[345,450],"http://sub.website.com/images/I/81OJ6qwKxyL._SY550_.jpg":[422,550],"http://sub.website.com/images/I/81OJ6qwKxyL._SY606_.jpg":[465,606],"http://sub.website.com/images/I/81OJ6qwKxyL._SY679_.jpg":[521,679]},"variant":"MAIN"},{"hiRes":"http://sub.website.com/images/I/71oHZNvsLbL._SL1500_.jpg","thumb":"http://sub.website.com/images/I/31lHNGD-ZDL._SS40_.jpg","large":"http://sub.website.com/images/I/31lHNGD-ZDL.jpg","main":{"http://sub.website.com/images/I/71oHZNvsLbL._SY355_.jpg":[197,355],"http://sub.website.com/images/I/71oHZNvsLbL._SY450_.jpg":[249,450],"http://sub.website.com/images/I/71oHZNvsLbL._SY550_.jpg":[305,550],"http://sub.website.com/images/I/71oHZNvsLbL._SY606_.jpg":[336,606],"http://sub.website.com/images/I/71oHZNvsLbL._SY679_.jpg":[376,679]},"variant":"PT01"},{"hiRes":"http://sub.website.com/images/I/91VCJAcIPEL._SL1500_.jpg","thumb":"http://sub.website.com/images/I/51G1gCkOFzL._SS40_.jpg","large":"http://sub.website.com/images/I/51G1gCkOFzL.jpg","main":{"http://sub.website.com/images/I/91VCJAcIPEL._SX355_.jpg":[355,341],"http://sub.website.com/images/I/91VCJAcIPEL._SX450_.jpg":[450,433],"http://sub.website.com/images/I/91VCJAcIPEL._SX425_.jpg":[425,409],"http://sub.website.com/images/I/91VCJAcIPEL._SX466_.jpg":[466,448],"http://sub.website.com/images/I/91VCJAcIPEL._SX522_.jpg":[522,502]},"variant":"PT02"},{"hiRes":"http://sub.website.com/images/I/912B68GN4aL._SL1500_.jpg","thumb":"http://sub.website.com/images/I/51elravQx6L._SS40_.jpg","large":"http://sub.websi
```

Comment: Which language are you running?

Comment: 2 ideas to tackle the task: 1.) Does your software / api provide the offset of a match in the tested string ?  That offset might allow to iteratively remove those prefixes from the test string that contain the matches found. 2.) Some apis provide a function to split a string into an array of substrings where the separator can be specified as a regex, optionally returning the separator matches as part of the substring array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An interesting question. In my understanding, the global flag cannot be "emulated" with other Regex syntax features.

One could try to emulate the global flag by a Regex repetition. You could expand your Regex so that it would match all appearances of `"hiRes":...` in a repetition loop. But then, you would see that although several URLs would be *matched* because of the loop, only the last appearance would be *captured*.

Switching on the global flag does more than just "continue looking". It switches on collecting more than one capture in an array. Having just a Regex loop does not do the same.

I'd like to show two examples what this means. To test the examples, use e.g. https://regex101.com/.

Here is a simple example, first with the global flag:

- Given text:  `a i b i c i`
- Regex: `/(i)/g`
- Result: array of three strings, `[0]="i" Pos.2, [1]="i" Pos.6, [2]="i Pos.10"`

Now without the global flag. To match more, we must add a repetition to the Regex that embraces several "i", and a condition that ignores text between two "i". Like this:

- Given text:  `a i b i c i`
- Regex: `/(?:(i)[^i]*)+/`
- Result: array of one string, `[0]="i" Pos.10`

This seems puzzling first, but it is correct. The Regex *matches* from position 2 until 10. And from that match, it *captures* the last "i" at position 10. So the repetition in the Regex causes not several captures but a longer matching. This is very different from what the global flag does.

To be precise, this behavior is called "greedy". It tries to *match* as much as possible. With the "U" flag or with certain quantifiers, you can make the Regex "ungreedy". In that case in the example above, your "ungreedily" captured "i" will be that of position 2.

As a more complex example, just enhance your initial Regex. It must ignore text from the URL until the next "hiRes", and a repetition be put around. Here it is:

`/\{(?:"hiRes":"([A-Za-z0-9%\/_:.-]+)"(?:[^"]|"(?!hiRes))*)+/`

The second part means: match as many as possible that is not a quota, or that is a quota not followed by hiRes. Like this, this syntax will dig until the begin of the next "hiRes". And then the repetition comes in and it starts over with "hiRes".

Try it out. It will capture only the last URL in your text.

Finally, this tutorial is very comprehensive: http://www.regular-expressions.info/